# xarry plotting - pixels with the maximum value are not drown with levels set

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-xarray

I have a DataArray in xarray and would like to plot it.

The data is called `da_landsat_daily_gci_2009_sel` and it looks like:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'GCI' (latitude: 106, longitude: 193)>
dask.array<shape=(106, 193), dtype=float64, chunksize=(106, 193)>
Coordinates:
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 -33.9 -33.950478 ... -39.149525 -39.2
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 140.8 140.84792 140.89584 ... 149.95209 150.0
    time       datetime64[ns] 2009-02-14
```

It has the GCI values ranging from 18.50 to 100.00.

I tried to plot the data with the xarray's [plot function](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/plotting.html#id2).

```
da_landsat_daily_gci_2009_sel.plot(levels=[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100], cmap=plt.cm.jet)
```

The plot looks like:
[image]

Obviously all the pixels with the GCI value of 100 are not drawn. It seems the `levels` param had the maximum value excluded. Did I do anything wrong or anything missing to include the maximum value?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that is because the interval borders are open, so its not including the value 100.

I am trying to reproduce the problem and I don't get the same behavior, values outside mi levels are included with a color for values outside the range, and a corresponding triangle in the tip of the colorbar.

Try forcing this behavior adding `extend='max'`

If you want more control over your plots I recommend using directly matplotlib instead of the implementation in xarray.